# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has') error /AdonisJs

Tags: adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

An error occurs when i use to show flash message in view adonis js

```
 @if(flashMessages.has('errors.title'))
  <p> {{ flashMessages.get('errors.title') }} </p>
 @endif
```

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Answer (score 0):

`flashMessage` is only available when rendering a page with `ctx.view.render()` or `ctx.view.renderAsync()`. Check where you render the page and make sure you're using the `view` member of the request's `HTTPContext` and not Adonis.js's `View` class (note the capital *V*).